# fill_between does not color adjacent intervals

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to fill between two adjacent intervals:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.randint(10,size=10),
                   'Color': ['r','r','r','r','r','r','g','g','g','g']})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,3))
ax.plot(df.Value)
ax.fill_between(df.index[df.Color == 'r'],
                df.Value[df.Color == 'r'], color='r')
ax.fill_between(df.index[df.Color == 'g'],
                df.Value[df.Color == 'g'], color='g')
```

Which gives me:

[image: fill_between example]

However, I would like to color the interval between index 5 and 6 as well (red).

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand, what "Color" is supposed to mean in this context. You have nine intervals to fill, but ten values for "Color".

Comment: Let's say we have a time-series with some dependent variable, and an exogenous variable, like a code. I want to show that a code (code red/green) was active at a certain interval, by means of filling the interval with a color.

Comment: So Color[i] defines the color in interval[i]  between point[i] and point[i+1], and the last Color value is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I mean

Answer (score 2):

You not only want to fill where the `Color` is `r`, but also where the color changes from red to green. You may formulate this as a condition and use the `where` argument to `fill_between`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.randint(10,size=10),
                   'Color': ['r','r','r','r','r','r','g','g','g','g']})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,3))
ax.plot(df.Value)

cond = df.Color == 'r'
cond2 = cond ^ np.concatenate(([0],np.diff(cond.astype(int)) == -1))

ax.fill_between(df.index, df.Value, where=cond2, color='r')
ax.fill_between(df.index, df.Value, where=~cond, color='g')

plt.show()
```

[image]

While this works fine in this case, it will fail when single intervals are involved. In that case you cannot use `fill_between`.

A most general solution for colorizing the area below a curve in the interval following a point could be the following. This creates a polygon of vertices based on the condition and plots a collection of those polygons in the respective color.

In this example a couple of test cases are shown:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

t1 = ['r','r','r','r','r','r','g','g','g','g']
t2 = ['r','g','r','r','g','r','g','g','r','g']
t3 = ['g','g','r','r','g','r','g','g','r','r']
t4 = ['g','r','g','g','r','g','g','g','g','r']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.randint(10,size=10),
                   'Color1': t1, "Color2": t2, 'Color3': t3, "Color4": t4})

def fill_intervals_post(x,y, color, cond, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    cond1 = color == cond
    start = np.diff(cond1.astype(int)) == 1
    end = np.diff(cond1.astype(int)) == -1
    inxstart = np.arange(len(color)-1)[start]+1
    inxend = np.arange(len(color)-1)[end]+2
    inx  = np.concatenate(([0,0],np.sort(np.concatenate((inxstart,inxend)))))
    xs = np.split(x, inx)[(~cond1).astype(int)[0]::2]
    ys = np.split(y, inx)[(~cond1).astype(int)[0]::2]
    verts = []
    for xi,yi in zip(xs,ys):
        xsi = np.concatenate((xi, xi[::-1]))
        ysi = np.concatenate((yi, np.zeros_like(yi)))
        verts.append(np.c_[xsi,ysi])
    p = PolyCollection(verts, color=cond)
    ax.add_collection(p)


fig,axes = plt.subplots(4,1,figsize=(8,9))

for i,ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(df.index.values, df.Value.values, color="k")    

    ax.set_title(df["Color{}".format(i+1)].values)
    fill_intervals_post(df.index.values,df.Value.values, 
                        df["Color{}".format(i+1)].values, "r", ax=ax)
    fill_intervals_post(df.index.values,df.Value.values, 
                        df["Color{}".format(i+1)].values, "g", ax=ax)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What if "Color" is `['r','g','r','g','r','g','r','g','r','g']`?

Comment: @Mr.T It sure depends on the desired outcome in a case like the one you mention. color is defined for points, not intervals; but yes, in a case like that one a different condition would be needed.

Comment: @Mr.T The problem is that fill_between won't work in the most general case. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this problem looks trivial but is not because of the irritating behavior of fill_between.